# WCF CallbackContract requires generated Interface instead of the one I specified in ServiceContract?

Tags: wcf, service, datacontractserializer

I have a Service that does a typical implementation of a CallbackContract like the following:
`[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(INerveCenterCallBack))]`

When I Add a ServiceReference to my WCF Service all works fine. Except when I open the **Reference.cs** that is generated (ie the auto-generated proxy) I notice that it does this:

```
CallbackContract=typeof(Synapse.NerveCenter.NerveCenterRef.INerveCenterServiceCallback)
```

It basically injects both the word "Service" and whatever the namespace I gave the ServiceReference itself at the time of creation "ie **NerveCenterRef**"

The problem now is when I attempt to connect to my Web Service it Requires that my InstanceContext use a concrete class that inherits from the Generated "**NerveCenterRef.INerveCenterServiceCallback**" instead of **INerveCenterCallBack** which I have shared in both a project used by both Client and Server?

Anyone experience the same or know of hints/why's this is occuring?

Comment: If you're sharing the interface, why do you need to create the proxy (i.e., use Add Service Reference)? You can simply use the DuplexChannelFactory<INerveCenterService> to create your client.